# Proxy authentification required on script tag REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, proxy

First time posting here so don't hesitate if you need/I forgot something. I looked everywhere and didn't find my answer (I guess I'm missing something).

My problem:
I created a REST SpringBoot application and put an index.html in resources/static to create a REACT front end (I don't want to use nodejs, maybe webpack if I really have to).

When I contact     localhost:8080/ I end up on my index.html but those scripts:

```
<script src="https://facebook.com/react-15.2.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://facebook.com/react-dom-15.2.0.js"></script>
```

needed to make REACT work provoke a Proxy Authentication Required error in the console log.

I am indeed behind my company's proxy. My IDE (IntelliJ) is configured with this proxy. My JVM takes those arguments to make it work:

-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myport -Dhttp.proxyUser=myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypwd -Dhttp.proxySet=true

and the application.properties has the following line:

server.use-forwarded-headers=true

I don't know what I should configure anymore to make it work. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:**

Facebook is a bad example as the proxy won't let me go on this site. I have updated my src to authorized sites (tried them on my browser and they worked). Still, I have the same error: 407 Proxy Authentification Required

Comment: When you say that you're seeing the error in the console log, you mean in your browser? In that case, it's your browser where you'll need to configure the proxy, but presumably that's already done? Can you access Facebook in a new tab in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the proxy is set on my browser and it was indeed there that I saw the error. I forgot that my company didn't allow the access to FB (I'll look for another place to load it) -_-' But I have the same issue with maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com and I can open it on my browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

The error is legit. This is the HTTP protocol. First I have the 407 error asking for the informations of my proxy, then those informations are sent throught a second request. Still, showing an error in the log is disturbing.